# in term of performance what are the main difference between WASI and C++ Addon when using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I am starting exploring WebAssembly and thought to myself if I prefer using c++ (not rust kotlin or any other supported language )
what is the difference between using these 2 techniques?
Of course, there is a difference in syntax here but eventually is there a difference in performance?

Answer (score 1):

after more investigation, i found this great talk

`Speed, Speed, Speed: JavaScript vs C++ vs WebAssembly`

By  Franziska Hinkelmann , Google

https://javascript-conference.com/blog/speed-speed-speed-javascript-vs-c-vs-webassembly-keynote/
with great examples and comparison of all the approach

in this example she calculated first 1M prime numbers

[image]

the conclusion are that in term of speed C++ addons are faster then webassembly

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly, and the tooling that supports it, is quite immature at the moment. The relative performance of various languages and tools will likely change quite a bit over time. I’d recommend using whichever language you are most happy with.